# How to set up PlayReady(and Widevine) PSSH when applying DRM to the Google Cloud Live Stream API

Tags: google-cloud-functions, live-streaming, drm, pssh

https://cloud.google.com/livestream/docs/reference/drm#encryptionkey

According to the documentation in the link above, there is no direct way to set up PSSH for PlayReady and Widevine when applying DRM to a stream from the GCP Live Stream API.

The PlayReady PSSH automatically generated by the GCP Live Stream API is missing the License URL (LA_URL) information, which prevents certain players from requesting a license.
I don't know why, but it definitely happens when encrypted with 'cbcs'

As you can see in the link, the DRM protocol only has a key_uri field for HLS, and I think a PSSH field should be added to it.
Is there any other way to specify the PSSH directly?

Comment: I think you need to raise a ticket with Google and ask why the PSSH does not include the LA_URL.